# How to set my Javascript datetimepicker format to regional settings

Tags: javascript, datepicker, datetimepicker, regional-settings, regional

This is my datetimepicker

```
$('input.bsdatepicker2').datetimepicker({  
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii',
        startDate: '+0d',
    });
```

How to set the datetimepicker date format to the computer's regional settings, whatever they are. 
I'm passing this date as a JSON and later converting it in c# and its causing me problems.

Comment: There's no standard way to determine the date format preferences of the host.

Comment: Oh yeah. Now i got it. The problem was that my PC regional settings are set as dd/MM/yyyy and I'm running my project in local host. That means the project expects the same date input but my datepicker is passing the date format like MM/dd/yyyy and since we are 14-th May my C# code tries to interpreted as 05.14.2016 and since there is no 14-th Month in the calendar im getting an error!